# How to restrict user from selecting previous values in picklist Journey

Tags: apex, trigger, picklist, validation-rule

Hi We have a unique scenario in the Picklist value selection for the users.

I have already checked on this earlier post from salesforce stackexchange [Trigger to validate selection of Pick-list values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42578/trigger-to-validate-selection-of-pick-list-values)

but this solution does not meet our needs.

THe requirement is we have a Journey status picklist field in salesforce which has the below values

1.Home Offer & Rent Quote
2.Frequently Asked Questions
3.Purchase Agreement Ready to Sign
4.Lease Application On its Way
5.Home Assessment Ready to Schedule
6.Home Assessment Complete
7.Closing Ready to Schedule
8.Home Offer and Rent Quote Ready to Expire
9.Expired Home Offer
10.Still Interested in Sparrow
11.General Outreach

Here when the user selects 1st value next time he cannot choose it he can only choose values in descending order they cannot go in reverse.

Please advise what or how to meet this requirement.

Comment: Does the `picklist values` also have the numbering with them? However you could still use `getPicklistvalues` from Describefieldresult.

Comment: @SachinHooda no the picklist does not have the numbering I just mention it to split them